# Each build on react native removes package name from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I having a strange problem with React native Android build. On each build/switch build variant/gradle sync etc it removes package property from `@react-native-masked-view` package causing  `No package name found` error. Don't know if its related to this package but it seems that not. Next I go to repo copy it from and paste into file. Build running as expected, but it removes it again, and next build fails. This is how it looks after any build

```
<manifest  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></manifest>
```

This is how its in repo

```
<manifest package="org.reactnative.maskedview" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` in the package.json file: is this installed or not?

If its installed, then try with delete `node_modules` folder and install it again by `yarn` or `npm install`

if its not installed, then install it by `yarn add @react-native-masked-view/masked-view` **or** `npm install --save @react-native-masked-view/masked-view`